# Why do I get 'No matches in call to initialiser' error when using Text?

Tags: swiftui, syntax-error

A tad confused here, still very much learning obviously.

Running Xcode, with SwiftUI.

I have data which is being read (successfully) from a JSON file, and when I try to use Text() to output an Int, I get the dreaded "No exact matches in call to initialiser' error, yet all of the other items output to the screen perfectly fine.

The data items are declared correctly as either String or Int, but I get this error only when trying to output the Int.

```
                Text(question.question)
                Text(question.sylabusItem)
                Text(question.correct)
                Text(correctAnswer)
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Text` has [quite a lot of initializers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text). Out of these, [one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:)-9d1g4) of them accepts a string.

However, none of them accept an `Int`.

To work around this you can use string concatenation.

```
Text("\(correctAnswer)") /// assuming correctAnswer is an Int
```

Comment: Awesome advice thanks ahem.  may I ask a follow up question then please... how do I output an Int other than the way you describe?

Comment: Np. Do you mean to display an Int?

Comment: Easiest way would be Text. But are you trying to show an image or something?

Comment: Yes how to display an Int.  I am simply trying to output a number.

Comment: :) Nothing, if that's the way it should be done, then I have learned something today.  Thanks

Comment: I am new to coding and SwiftUI, at my age it is a challenge haha.  Thanks for your help, really appreciated.

Comment: @John yep, Text is probably the best way to display Ints/numbers.